# PHP cURL - url is printed out incomplete in get request

Tags: php, http, curl

I did this get request with curl, and I'm trying to call an url passing a parameter to it, but it seems not to work correctly. This is the php code of my curl request:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$params = array('code'=> '123123');
$query = http_build_query($params);
try{
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/foo/addProduct?'.$query);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);

    //DEBUG INFO
    $information = curl_getinfo($curl);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Now when I try to print out the request and response headers of curl I get this situation:

```
Array
(
[url] => https://www.website.com/
[content_type] => text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 1088
[request_size] => 1209
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 1
[total_time] => 0.706971
[namelookup_time] => 3.3E-5
[connect_time] => 3.4E-5
[pretransfer_time] => 9.6E-5
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 53855
[speed_download] => 76177
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0.201504
[redirect_time] => 0.447898
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 193.42.160.33
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 192.168.1.51
[local_port] => 61262
[request_header] => GET / HTTP/1.1
)
```

I'd expect the url to be

```
https://www.website.com/foo/addProduct?code=123123
```

Am I right?

Comment: Try adding in the first option for getinfo from this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php I suspect it will give just a single response but does it give the same URL.

Comment: I get `Array
(
    [url] => https://www.website.com/foo/addProduct?code=123123
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 404 ...`, but I don't know what's in `$headers` and I don't have the real URL. Maybe the site does a redirect?

Comment: I've copy pasted this code (replaced `$headers` with `[]`) and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

you are absolutely correct, the only way that code would generate `[url] => https://www.website.com/`  is if curl was [Location-redirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) (becuase you used `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`).

remove `curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true );` (because of https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65348 ), and do `curl_setopt_array ( $curl, [CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,CURLOPT_STDERR => STDOUT] );` , and you should be able to see it for yourself.